# Long-running Python process that accepts inputs from another non-Python process

Tags: python, objective-c, ipc

I'm designing a system like this: a Python process (let's call it "server") accepts inputs from another process ("client", written in Objective-C) on the same machine and returns outputs to the client.

What's a good architecture for this system? I mean, what's a good protocol for server/client communication? I think making the server an HTTP service is overkill because the client always lives on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue it's not the `HTTP` that adds a lot of overhead, but the `TCP` 3-way connection handshake.

Having said that, a lot of systems use TCP for inter-process communication, so if you want to use HTTP, it's only a very small extra load on top.

Of course with HTTP, you are creating a new connection with each request, however this is not so bad - you should be able to make each HTTP call within 1 or 2ms.

With HTTP comes a lot of nice properties like not having to maintain a persistent TCP connection, a ton of great libraries to easily make/receive your requests, and the request/response model seems to suit your system needs.